# CODEIGNITER - Pasar un numero X desde un input a una funcion dentro de cotrolador

Tags: php, css, html5, mvc, codeigniter

tengo poco tiempo trabajando con codeigniter.

tengo un problema con un sistema de sorteo al azar.

en esta primera funcion, cargo una vista y dentro de esa vista hay un formulario con un input donde se ingresa una X cantidad de ganadores, ya sea 2 o 3 o 4. cuando le doy al boton submit debe enviarme a otra vista donde me debe mostrar una lista con la X cantidad de registros que escribi en el input.

esta es la primera funcion que llama el formulario donde ingreso X cantidad.

```
public function datoSorteo()
{
    $this->load->view('Plantilla/header-rifa');
    $this->load->view('sorteo');        
}
```

esta es la segunda funcion que lista los registros de la base de datos
donde dice $this->db->limit($num); es donde se debe almacenar la cantidad que se escribio en el input. Ejemplo: tengo una tabla en la BD con 10 personas registradas, y quiero elegir "3" ganadores al azar

```
    public function sorteoParti()
{

            $this->db->limit($num);
            $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');
            $result =$this->db->get('rifa');
            $datas = array('consulta'=>$result);
            $this->load->view('Plantilla/header-consult');
            $this->load->view('lista_rifa', $datas);
}
```

este es el formulario donde ingreso el numero de ganadores.. "num" es donde se almacena la variable que quiero pasar a $this->db->limit($num); en la segunda funcion "sorteoParti()"

```
<form class="container" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>prueba-nws/index.php/Rifa/sorteoParti" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Cantidad de Ganadores</label>
  <input name="num" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ganadores">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Elegir al azar</button>
</form>
```

agradezco mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente estás enviando el formulario a la función correcta (en la que usas `$num` para hacer el `limit` en tu consulta) pero lo que te falta hacer es capturar desde el servidor el campo que contiene ese valor enviado.

```
public function sorteoParti(){
  $num = $this->input->post('num');

  $this->db->limit($num);
  $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');
  $result =$this->db->get('rifa');
  $datas = array('consulta'=>$result);
  $this->load->view('Plantilla/header-consult');
  $this->load->view('lista_rifa', $datas);
}
```

A través de `$this->input->post()` podemos capturar desde el Controlador la información enviada desde la Vista a través de POST.

Comment: excelente, era el eslavon perdido del codigo, muchas gracias hermano, ya esta realizando la operacion, ademas en la linea [$this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');] se cambio el ASC a RANDOM